# How to display visual interactive calendar on own web app using Google Client API gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, calendar

I'm very new to Ruby on Rails and I was wondering how I would go about implementing a calendar on my web app that a user could sync with their own google calendar, so that it would show their events. Ideally they would be able to add events to this calendar too, which would update their google calendar. I just don't know how I would start this. I know that there are insert and get methods provided by the gem, but I don't know where I would be calling them?

At the moment I have a User model (+controller) and a sessions controller, with a few views for the website. Would I need to create another model 'Calendar and a controller for that? Would calendar events also be another model or should they be handled within the calendar class? Would the google client api gem methods be used in the sessions controller or the calendar controller?

I haven't made my calendar yet, but I want to do it using javascript. Could any of you recommend any pre-made javascript calendars?

Thanks in advance and sorry for all the questions, I'm just trying to get my head round this!

Answer (score 0):

You're doing too much at once. Specifically you want to:

- Create, Update, Read & Delete calendar events (on your server, in your database)
- Consume a google API to synchronise your copy of the user's calendar with google
- Add some javascript whizzbang to make it all snappy and buzzword-compliant.

That's too much too start. Focus on doing these three things sequentially. Start with a rails app that has the following models: User, Calendar, Event and allows users to edit their calendars.

Don't start thinking about google until you get that first version working.

Comment: ok, I have been looking at FullCalendar (http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/) would this speed up the process at all? I only want the calendar to reflect their google calendar, I wouldn't want to have another separate calendar system